# Asp.net Core. Create [FromQuery] paremeters instance if request querystring is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have Asp.Net Core controller with method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]TestModel bodyParameters, [FromQuery]TestModel queryParameters)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var rng = new Random();
    return Ok(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    }).ToArray());
}
```

I send POST request like http://localhost:57737/WeatherForecast with the body. And wait that bodyParameters will have values and queryParameters will be null. But queryParameters is not null, with null properties
and ModelState.IsValid is false i.e. TestModel has [Required] properties

**Issue**
What should I do to make `queryParameters = null` if request query `string` is `empty`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is nothing you can do, since there is no way for the binder to know that you actually wanted to send all null parameters.
Probably check that queryParameters.Id has a null value (or invalid) and return BadRequest()